# How to handle this java race condition without use of synchronous block?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, race-condition

I am using spring boot as back end.
Consider the following two operation sequences that can be triggered (in the worst case) by the same user from front end:

A. reduce product quantity (from front end) -> update the quantity in db -> read from db to check if product quantity has fallen below a minimum -> if yes, add record in redis

B. increase product quantity (from front end) -> update the quantity in db -> check if record is present in redis -> if yes, read from db to check if product quantity is above minimum now -> if yes, remove record from redis

I am considering the situation when A is followed by B and B reads from redis before A adds the record in redis. Currently I am thinking of using threadpool where any process(for a product) checks if a thread by the name of the product is present in the pool and proceeds accordingly. Is there any better solution to this problem ?
I am not using synchronous block as it might become a bottleneck.

Comment: " if yes, read from db to check if product quantity is above minimum now " - why do you need this extra read? Don't you know the "current" quantity after the update?

Comment: @DavidSoroko thanks for the info, anyway sql operations that will be synchronous. The part related to redis is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

In the common Spring scenario, A and B will be executed on different threads so you don't need your own thread pool. Since you require consistency between the data in the db and in Redis, some sort of orchestration is needed. This is commonly done via transactions, see for example here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Note: *"update the quantity in db -> read from db to check if product quantity has fallen below a minimum"* this extra read is not necessary as you can return current db values using `UPDATE ... RETURNING`

Comment: I don't need consistency between data in db and in redis. Because A and B are executed on different threads, there is a chance that sequence of events in A and B might not be as intended (there might be race condition between A and B) as I have explained in the question.